# In ProductSell model there is a date column type is varchar and format d/m/Y how can I retrieve data using wherebetween?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have a model ProductSell with a column date which type is varchar  and format is d/m/Y .

Suppose I have two date 31/03/2019 and 01/04/2019 .
I want to fetch data between these dates 
I am trying like

```
$productsale=ProductSell::whereBetween('date',[$request->from,$request- 
>to])->get();
```

when date is 
    31/03/2019 and 01/04/2019 
this is not working but when date is
01/03/2019 and 31/03/2019 it working fine

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason for using the data type `varchar(n)` rather than `datetime` for your dates?

Comment: I did not know that date type should be date or datetime  and I have already used it as varchar and I have inserted many data . Is there any solution without changing date format and type ? @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, change the datatype from a varchar to a date, datetime or timestamp.  The problem here is that the database doesn't understand how to order the date columns chronologically -- since it thinks it's dealing with standard text and wants to sort them alphabetically.  Using datetime allows it to sort the rows by date a select the subset you want.

Fortunately you can often just change the datatype of the column and as long as the values are in a standard format (And your table isn't millions and millions of records) it will usually convert them just fine. I'm assuming you're using mysql here, but most databases should have something similar.

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> MODIFY <columnName> datetime;
```

Of course, I'd suggest making a copy of the table and trying out the conversion on that first -- just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndyChern  but it set date=0000-00-00 00:00:00 then I update date=create_at